# incompatible return with anyMatch and try / catch exception

Tags: java, java-8

i have this generic method in java 8. this method get Array list and for each element in this list get all field in object for verifying if any value is null or empty string

i have this error

**Incompatible types. Found: 'void', required: 'boolean'**

code:

```
public boolean nullFieldCreated() {
        return ((ArrayList) object).forEach(obj ->
                Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                        .filter(field -> (field.getName() != "id" && field.getName() != "cardId"))
                        .anyMatch(fieldValue -> {
                            try {
                                return fieldValue.get(obj) == null || fieldValue.get(obj).equals(EMPTY);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return false;
                        }));
}
```

For this object:

> {
>
> ```
> "trainingList": [
>     {
>         "id": "",
>         "startDate": "",
>         "duration": "",
>         "topic": "",
>         "trainingTypeId": "",
>         "trainingPlaceId": ""
>     }
> ],
> "driverLicenseList": [
>     {
>         "id": "",
>         "date": "",
>         "classDriverLicenseId": ""
>     }
> ] }
> ```

this method get any object without specifying type, objectifs is detect all attributes declared in this object and verify if any one is null or empty and retur true if is the case or false

how to use:

```
if (!new NullField(request.getTrainingList()).nullFieldCreated())) 
    do something;
else
    do other;
```

Comment: What should this method return? In other words, when should this method return true?

Comment: You should specify _where_ you get the error. In any case, what do you expect the value of `forEach` to be? Finally, you _definitely_ don't want to limit your code to explicit `ArrayList`; you can be as generic as `Collection` (or even `Iterable`) and say `objects.stream().flatMap(o -> Arrays.stream(o.getClass().getDeclaredFields())`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because forEach is a void function. You can fix it like this:

```
public boolean nullFieldCreated() {
    boolean result = false;

    for (Object obj : object) {
      result =
          Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
              .filter(field -> (field.getName() != "id" && field.getName() != "cardId"))
              .anyMatch(
                  fieldValue -> {
                    try {
                      return fieldValue.get(obj) == null || fieldValue.get(obj).equals(EMPTY);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                  });
      if (result) break;
    }
    
    return result;
  }
```